# Div does not follow the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

In the following code, I hope my div will follow my mouse in red background but it does not, what's the reason for that?

CSS

```
.dropdown1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 10px;
  background: #2b4557;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

JSX

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const descBox = useRef(null);
  const handleMove = (e) => {
    console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    descBox.current.style.left = e.clientX;
    descBox.current.style.top = e.clientY;
  };
  return (
    <div
      onMouseMove={handleMove}
      style={{ height: "300px", width: "100%", backgroundColor: "red" }}
    >
      <div className="dropdown1" ref={descBox}>
        123asdfsfdafffasdfasfdsajkj
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please run the code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-wave-q0bfm1?file=/src/App.js:0-526)

And here's a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the unit bro

```
descBox.current.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
descBox.current.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
```